# Data Extension Retention Policy - Individual Records - does the period reset upon upsert/update?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm reading the documentation on retention policies for data extensions.

One thing is unclear - hoping someone can clarify.

If I set the retention policy to work on individual records, what happens if I update an existing record? Does the retention period reset? Or does the retention period strictly apply to the date/time the row was created?

Comment: The only time it can be 'reset' is when you choose the 'all data' or 'all data and DE' options - which you can select the Reset Retention Period On Import option which will reset the date for all records. The individual records retention does not give this option. You would need to either create your own retention via SQL or reinject the records once they are removed via import or SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The retention is set when the record is added to the Data Extension. At that time, there is a timestamp created in the database, which is not visible in the application. That field stores the date that the record was added. It then uses that field to compare it to the retention, to determine whether or not the record needs to be removed.

If a record is updated, it does not change that field's date. So if you add a record, with 180 day retention, it will be removed once that time has elapsed regardless of if it has been updated or not.